# How to allow anon user that enters existing contact email into webform to add infomation to that matching contact

Tags: upgrade, checksum, anonymous-user

I just inherited a contact list of 2164 contacts that has name and email only that opted in to our campaign. I want to to import into to CiviCRM and mass email the group to encourage them to give us additional information and volunteer for the campaign.

Our existing supporter webform https://emptyhometax.org/join-us-at-yes-on-empty-home-tax-2022/ i  gives "Please correct the following errors in the form fields below:
A record already exists with the same information." if a user with an email already in the system tries to fill out form.

How can I get the new people to be able to add additional information into their contact via a webform? Or is there another way to easily do this without the user having to create an account and sign in? I essentially want them to the fill out the existing webform and have their contact updated with the additional information they provide.

Would I just send this checksum link
https://emptyhometax.org/civicrm/profile/edit/?reset=1&gid=2&contact.checksum&id=contact.contact_id and that would automatically connect user to their profile?

Answer (score 1):

Yes use the checksum - to avoid overwriting if people may forward it, you can put eg two buttons on your mailer
1/ update your details Peter
2/ add your details if you are not Peter